# Do resistive heating elements age due to the passage of current or due to the heat they are subjected to?

Tags: heat, heater, resistivity

It is well known that resistive heating elements (such as lightbulb filaments, or furnace elements) have a finite lifetime.

If I heated (or heat-cool cycled) a resistive heating element to the exact same extent as it would experience if it were passing current and heating itself, would it have the same lifetime or an increased lifetime?

This is a general question, but I am motivated by wanting to understand the lifetime of certain expensive furnace heating elements [such as as MoSi2](https://www.kanthal.com/en/products/furnace-products/electric-heating-elements/molybdenum-disilicide-heating-elements/) (which has been used since the 1950s), and if a hybrid approach of pre-heating the chamber using combustion before taking it to a much higher temperature resistively could add useful lifetime to the element.

Comment: Most types of components age faster (often exponentially faster) with higher temperature.  I would expect a heating element to be similar.

Comment: I suppose it might not properly take into account fatigue from thermal cycling because things heat up differently for internal vs external. Also, external heating won't take into account electromigration effects, if there are any that matter. But why would you preheat with combustion when you could just electrically ramp up the heat?

Comment: combustion heating will become progressively more expensive, probably best avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about MoSi2 heater but foil, cartridge and armored heaters *are* susceptible to thermal aging.

There is an accelerating aging issue, if only because oxydation is faster at high temperature (AFAIK most if not every chemical reaction is faster at high temperature).

Also the whole assembly (heater, insulator, armor) is subjected to mechanical stresses due to thermal expansion which definitely doesn't help.

In my experience the main issues for premature heater failure are:

- Excessive power density: the process has trouble conducting away the heat (hot spots) so the heater is overloaded. As in don't use a water heater for oil. This is a design error, so it doesn't apply to your question. Been there, done that.
- Thermal coupling to the process: similar as above, the heater can't transfer enough heat away. If assembled correctly doesn't apply, of course.
- Mechanical/chemical issues: *the* plague of the armored heaters like these you linked. Either armor corrosion (oxydation or process environment) or cracking (especially near welds or terminal attachment) due to thermal expansion, (mis)assembly stress or similar.

In my experience (mostly conventional resistance heaters, not your exotic material ones) the electrical element almost never fail; 99% of the failure are insulation ones (punctured armor) unless the insulator (for mineral insulation) was badly packed (so a manufacturing issue).

As for the external preheating: *assuming* you faults are due to the electrical element thermal cycling it could help somewhat. Due to thermal resistances (element to insulator to armor to process) when you heat electrically the element is the hottest part while the process is the coldest; when preheating externally the element would be the coldest one.

In any case probably the gain would vary depending on your duty cycle. A burner preheater would 'save' your heater only during preheating while probably most of the time the process would use the electric heater at it's operating temperature. And Arrhenius equation says that reaction speed is *exponential* with temperature (assuming it's a chemical issue). It seems that your MoSi2 are designed for high temperatures so I assume the effect would be more noticeable.

In my opinion the best way would be as recommended in a comment: ramp up the temperature *slowly* since there are non negligible thermal masses to be accounted for. In this way you minimize thermal expansion issues. And of course assembly correctly the heater (*especially* if it's expensive!)

Finally: are you sure preheating with a combustion heater is cheaper? you'll have more equipment, more safety issues *and* more maintenance to do. And gas/oil to burn is not cheap either.

Answer (score 1):

The failure modes of a heating element are rarely related to the passage of electrical current itself. The only possible mechanism I can think of is [eletromigration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromigration) and it really doesn't happen much in an AC powered circuits and is important at different scales anyway.

What else happens, then?

1. Mechanical stress because of the thermal expansion/shrinking. The heating mechanism and the heat exchange conditions combined mean that the inside of the conductor is hotter and tries to expands more than the outside. This imposes a tensile stress over the outer layers and may lead to cracking.

Here, preheating or slower heating may help because the hotter material is usually softer and less prone to cracking.

2. Thermal transport of a material from the heating element to its surroundings. This is the main failure mode in the non-halogen incandescent lightbulbs. The wire simply evaporates and condenses somewhere colder (e.g. on the inner glass surface). Other types of heating elements suffer as well.

Here, preheating is of no importance.

3. Thermal transport of a material between different parts of the heating element. E.g. in halogen bulbs, the wire material recrystallizes into bigger crystals, gradually degrading the smooth cylindrical shape of the wire.

Again, no luck with preheating.

4. Chemical processes (e.g. oxidation) between the heating element and its surroundings.

Preheating won't help either.

All of the above applies to the resistive material itself, as well as its tubing, electrical insulation and everything else around, to a different extent.

---

Also keep in mind that one usually cannot heat the heating element to its working temperature by external means without overheating its surroundings. The extreme example is the lightbulb again - the wire heats as high as 3000C while the glass bulb will melt as low as 700C.

Preheating (electrical) is used for some lightbulbs - e.g. for the expensive ones used in cinema or optical measurement equipment. In standby mode, they are powered with ~10% of their rated voltage. This makes them emit a negligible amount of deep red light (and of course some infrared) This also costs some electricity, but the bulb life gets as much as 10 times longer (or more). This also simplifies their power supply, because it has to deal with much less inrush current.

I don't know how MoSi2 heating elements behave, but it probably won't hurt to start them at half voltage (e.g. two in series), wait a while (how much is a while depends on how much time your furnace needs to reach its working temperature) and then apply the full power.

If there is a thermostat and it works by simply switching the heating elements on and off, it is also possible to make it alternate between full and half power (or between zero and half, depending on the heat loss). This will also reduce the thermal stress of the elements, as well as the whole furnace.